# Is the code run every new object created?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

if i have following code :

```
class Stand {

public static const STAND_LIST:Array = new Array();
STAND_LIST[0] = new Array();
STAND_LIST[1] = new Array();

public function Stand() {
    //constructor
    }
}
```

is the STAND_LIST[0] keeps created every new instance of Stand created? or is it created just once?

if it's created every new instance of Stand created, how do i make it run just once?(like initializing const)

Comment: Its static so just once for the `Stand` class, `Stand.STAND_LIST`, but it won't be available for an instance of `Stand`, `var stand:Stand = new Stand(); stand.STAND_LIST; // error`. Also you might want to use this `public static var STAND_LIST:Array = [[], []];`.

Comment: thx for the response!. now i know it is just run once from your comment and bedwyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statics are initialized once for the class; they are not initialized each time a new class instance is created.

[Here's](http://life.neophi.com/danielr/2006/12/static_initializers_in_as3_1.html) a helpful link regarding static initializers in ActionScript:

[This SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627631/actionscript-whats-the-defined-order-for-initializing-internal-static-instance) briefly discusses when statics are initialized.